# concatenating two part-words together

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, string-concatenation

I am helping someone with their wedding and i am using excel for the table plans for their dinner.

When i originally set this up, i was stupid enough to make two people, not as a couple, but as individual people.

So i have mr person and mrs person.

Now i want to make these two individuals into one cell row in excel.

i.e. before; | mr person | 72 land lane | 1234-5678.

And mrs person | 72 land lane | 1234-5678.

How would i make it so that it would be | mr & mrs person | 72 land lane | 1234-5678 | ?

P.s. some people on the list are singles! so i cant find and replace, to add a mrs part to each person!

Comment: i'm sorry but down-voting without a reason is just plain wrong and unfair

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your name, address and phone number are in different columns I'd use a COUNTIF statement in Column D to identify those at the same address (assuming they all live together!) You'll need to adjust the range, and insert a blank column into Column A.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$9,C2)>1,"Mr & "& C2,"")
```

This will concatenate all the couples, you can then use the below formula in a different column to identify the partner to be deleted:

```
=IF(LEFT(C2,8)="Mr & Mr ","DELETE","")
```

Comment: Glad you had the time to edit my response... more importantly did you try and use my suggestion?